# Reinitialize datatable using the new API

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've found some SO threads about reinitializing a datatable using the old API, but I think they're deprecated now.

I have an existing rendered datatable. I would like to refresh it with new settings. Using the new API, how would I do the following:

```
var dataTable = $('table.dataTable').DataTable();

var newDataTableSettings = {
    data: { /* some data */ },
    columns: { /* some columns*/ },
    bFilter: false,
    // etc...
};

// something like dataTable.clear().data(newDataTableSettings).draw()
```

My closest attempt:

```
dataTable.clear().draw() 
dataTable.rows.add({ /* some data */ }).draw();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**`destroy`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option :

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    data:  [{ test : 'test' }, { test : 'qwerty'}],    
    columns : [ { data : 'test', title: 'test' } ]    
});
```

reinitialise with new data and removed search capabilities .

```js
$("#reinit").on('click', function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        destroy: true, //<--- here
        data: [{ newCol : '100010'}, { newCol : '234234'}],
        columns: [ { data : 'newCol', title: 'header' } ],
        searching: false
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3sonfsfm/

If you use an options literal you *must* reset it before reusing it :

```js
var options = {
    data:  [{ test : 'test' }, { test : 'qwerty'}],    
    columns : [ { data : 'test', title: 'test' } ]    
}

$("#reinit").on('click', function() {
    options = {}; //<--- RESET
    options.destroy = true;
    options.data = [{ newCol : '100010'}, { newCol : '234234'}];
    options.columns = [ { data : 'newCol', title: 'header' } ];
    options.searching = false;
    $('#example').DataTable(options).draw();
});
```

This is because the `options` object is enriched with different values such as `aaData`, `aoColumns` an so on, which will conflict if you specify new `data` and new `columns`.